# Draw Polylines and Polygons on Map in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Actually i am beginner to android development

I want to draw route(blue line) between my current location to marker  i touch(i have some location markers on map,locations of clients)??

Answer (score 0):

A Polyline is a series of connected line segments. Polylines are useful to represent routes, paths, or other connections between locations on the map.

1. Create a PolylineOptions object and add points to it. Each point represents a location on the map, which you define with a LatLng object containing latitude and longitude values. The code sample below creates a polyline with 6 points.
2. Call GoogleMap.addPolyline() to add the polyline to the map.

```
Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .clickable(true)
        .add(
                new LatLng(-35.016, 143.321),
                new LatLng(-34.747, 145.592),
                new LatLng(-34.364, 147.891),
                new LatLng(-33.501, 150.217),
                new LatLng(-32.306, 149.248),
                new LatLng(-32.491, 147.309)));
```

Set the polyline's *clickable* option to *true* if you want to handle click events on the polyline.

You can customise stroke width, stroke color, and joint type:

```
polyline.setEndCap(new RoundCap());
polyline.setWidth(12);
polyline.setColor(Color.parse("#0000ff"));
polyline.setJointType(JointType.ROUND);
```